# MySQL Improve performance execution time

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to improve performance of following query which took 93.2 sec to execute query below:

```
SELECT  year(date), month(date), `country_name_name`,
        CEIL(count(res.`user_xmpp_login`) /DAY(LAST_DAY(date))) as avgUser,
        CEIL(count(res.user)/DAY(LAST_DAY(date))) as avgPurchase
    FROM  
    (   SELECT  DATE(`user_registration_timestamp`) as date,
                user_country,
                NULL as user, `user_xmpp_login`
            FROM  users
            WHERE  `user_registration_timestamp` >= "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
              AND  `user_registration_timestamp`  < "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
            UNION  ALL 
        SELECT  DATE(`ts`) as date, user_country, user, NULL as `user_xmpp_login`
            FROM  purchase_log p
            INNER JOIN  users u  ON u.`user_xmpp_login` = p.`user`
            WHERE  `ts` >= "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
              AND  `ts`  < "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
              AND  result in ('ok', 'cancelled', 'pending') 
    ) AS res
    INNER JOIN  countries c  ON c.`country_id` = res.`user_country`
    INNER JOIN  country_names cn
               ON (cn.`country_name_country` = c.`country_id`
              AND  cn.`country_name_language` = 'en')
    GROUP BY  1,2,3
    ORDER BY  4 DESC,5 DESC, 3 ASC;
```

Explain command shows:
   [image]
And structure of each table is:

purchase table:

```
CREATE TABLE `purchase` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `result` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `iuser` (`user`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12710221 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_xmpp_login` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_registration_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_xmpp_login_UNIQUE` (`user_xmpp_login`),
  KEY `user_country_FK` (`user_country`),
  KEY `user_registration_timestamp` (`user_registration_timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_country_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`user_country`)
         REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33504745 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

countries table

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=508 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

country names

```
CREATE TABLE `country_names` (
  `country_name_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_name_country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_name_language` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_name_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_name_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `country_name_country_language_UNIQUE`
            (`country_name_country`,`country_name_language`),
  KEY `country_name_language` (`country_name_language`),
  CONSTRAINT `country_name_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country_name_country`)
        REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45793 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Is there any recommendations?

Comment: @e4c5 , I've done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you time each subquery, I think you will find `users` is the slowest component.

The `purchase_log` subquery can probably be improved with this "covering" `INDEX(result, ts, user)`.

Combine the two "country" tables!.  Use `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` for the `PRIMARY KEY` and the `JOINs` to other tables.  It is only 2 bytes, unlike `INT`, which is 4 bytes and `VARCHAR...`, which is 3 bytes (in this case).

You mention `ts`, but I don't see where it is coming from.  If it is in `purchase_log`, then that table needs `INDEX(user, ts)`.

What percentage of the `users` involved 2015?  If it is more than about 20%, the `INDEX(user_registration_timestamp)` won't help.

Consider:  Get rid of PRIMARY KEY (`country_name_id`), and promote the `UNIQUE` key to `PRIMARY`.

Comment: thx, what do u mean by your first sentences, what should I do to solve? Do u mean I don't use DATE(`user_registration_timestamp`) in subquery and instead I use field itself? about combine two country tables, u mean I use one table rather than two? the problem here is  country_names because some countries have more than 2 translations for their name. Finally, what's your solution for numbers of users more than 20%, that's it is more than this mount.

Comment: `SELECT .. FROM users ..` is probably the slowest part; first verify that it is the slowest part, then think about whether it can be rewritten in any way.  Changing `DATE(...)` won't help.  Are there a lot of duplicate rows coming from the query?

Comment: The unique id for a country can be the standard 2-letter codes (language-independent), thereby avoiding the INT and the need for the first of the two tables.

Comment: 20% is a "rule of thumb" on whether the optimizer will use the index versus scan the table.  A shorter time range would probably demonstrate this.

Comment: We have 7000 rows for country name that's not possible to use  2 letter code.

Comment: Both subquery are together 4.12 s, 3.10s is user part. 27 sec for union part of subquery, and when I have executed all, then 93s.

Comment: 7000 distinct country_codes?  What planet are you on?  Note:  I am referring to the _code_, not the _name_.  `DE` is the code for English "Germany" and German "Deutschland".

Comment: Your timings imply that the `JOINs` are the most costly part?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem seems to be in your users table. Remember, mysql can only use one index per table for most situations. On your users table, the `user_xmpp_login_UNIQUE` column has been used to join it to the purchase_log table. There fore, the user_registration_timestamp index is not being used on the comparison involving the timestamp column.

One suggestion is to create a composite index on the `user_xmpp_login` and `user_registration_timestamp` columns.

Comment: Thanks 4 your answer, let me to check it with your propose and I'll tell u the result.